# Aligning button and text in navbar in twitter bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have written the following html with Bootstrap 2.3.2 included and no other css:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="container">
            (...)
            <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav">
                    (...)
                </ul>
                <form id="login-form" class="navbar-form pull-right">
                    <span class="navbar-text">Hello, username!</span>
                    <button id="logout" class="btn">Log out</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I make it so that the log out button aligns with the text and `.navbar` correctly? Currently the button sticks to the bottom of the line, which is the bottom of the `.navbar` because of the `.navbar-text`.

The problem can be viewed [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/8884434/test.html).

Comment: Please post your CSS and preferably make a jsfiddle. We don't know what you're looking at, so we don't know what would make it look correct.

Comment: Eliminate the `margin-top:5px` of the button …?

Answer (score 1):

You can reset the button's margin via CSS:

```
.navbar .btn {
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

Comment: This is indeed a working solution, but is there a way to do it with bootstrap classes only?

Comment: I don't know... I fiddled around with your markup in [bootply.com](http://bootply.com) and the only solution I've found is resetting the margin